# The tweets of the Moral Foundations Twitter Corpus

Tags: twitter, moral-foundations

The Moral Foundations Twitter Corpus (MFTC) is an annotated dataset that has been used in various research studies. However, it seems that its [official repository](https://osf.io/k5n7y/) has only the annotations with references to the tweets. Unfortunately with the change towards X, the Twitter API has become ever more restrictive and combining annotations with tweet texts is no longer trivial.

Does anyone have (or know a place where to find) the combined corpus?

Thanks!